# React onItemClick not triggering single item after mapping

Tags: reactjs

In react I am trying to click on an item after mapping a series of data. It looks like this:

```
{Members.map(m => (
    <Menu
      key={m.username}
      onItemClick={console.log(m.username)}
    >
      <Menu.Item>
        <ul>
          <li>
            {m.firstName} {m.lastName}
          </li>
          <li>
            {m.username}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  ))}
```

Right now I have multiple Menu items after mapping out all the members. I have the onclick on the parent `<Menu>` but when I try clicking on them after being listed out, it prints every username.

Can this be done to only print out the `<Menu>` I click on?

EDIT

When I try to have onItemClick like this:

```
onItemClick={() => {
   console.log(m.username);
}}
```

I get an error that says: `Failed prop type: Prop 'onItemClick' in 'Menu' conflicts with props: 'children'. They cannot be defined together, choose one or the other.`

Comment: before giving you a big hint, ask yourself: what should `onItemClick` be? a function perhaps? in your current code is `onItemClick` a function?

Comment: also what is `tm`. it's not defined in your codeblock

Comment: @azium I edited my question above. I explain what happens when I try `onItemClick` a different way. Also edited my code to match correctly.

Comment: just to clarify, you want a **menu** *for every* member? or you want a menu **item** for every member?

Comment: Right now I have Menu for each member.

Comment: what library are you using? Where does `Menu` and `Menu.Item` come from?

Comment: It is from Semantic UI. https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu#menu-example-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error and the documentation are very clear. Either you use `onItemClick` together with the `data` prop and no children, or you pass your own children, like you are, and write click handlers directly on them.

```
  {Members.map(m => (
    <Menu
      key={m.username}
    >
      <Menu.Item onClick={() => { // use onClick here
        console.log(m.username)
      }}>
        <ul>
          <li>
            {m.firstName} {m.lastName}
          </li>
          <li>
            {m.username}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  ))}
```